# Oracle ODBC client configuration missing variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, odbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to configure an ODBC connection for an Oracle DB using unixODBC drivers.
For that I followed [this Oracle's guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/releasenote-odbc-ic.html).

First, I successfully installed the ODBC client and driver.

```
# dnf install unixODBC oracle-instantclient-sqlplus oracle-instantclient-odbc
```

Odbcinst shows the driver defaults correctly.

```
# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Then, the guide suggests to configure ODBC with the `odbc_update_ini.sh` script.

```
# find / -name "odbc_update_ini.sh"
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/odbc_update_ini.sh
```

For that, I should input the <ODBCDM_Home> as the first argument.

```
Usage: odbc_update_ini.sh <ODBCDM_Home> [<Install_Location> <Driver_Name> <DSN> <ODBCINI>]
```

It happens that this script cannot find the INI file.

```
# /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/odbc_update_ini.sh "/usr/local"
 *** INI file not found. Driver Manager not installed!
```

It seems there should be an `$ODBCDM_Home` environment variable set, but it does not exist, and Oracle's guide does not instruct us on how to set it.

```
# cat /usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/odbc_update_ini.sh
(...)    
# Check whether Driver Manager is installed or not
if [ ! -f  $ODBCDM_HOME/etc/odbc.ini  -o  ! -f $ODBCDM_HOME/etc/odbcinst.ini ]
then
   echo " *** INI file not found. Driver Manager not installed!"
   exit
fi
(...)
```

I could not find meaninful information about this issue for now.

I'm at a loss now.
Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Update ini file `/etc/odbc.ini` manually with your preferred editor. The syntax is simple, you don't need script `odbc_update_ini.sh` which does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I believe is the correct procedure to configure Oracle's ODBC while using `odbc_update_ini.sh` script.

After installing ODBC driver manager and Oracle's driver, by default we must start Oracle's script in the following manner.

---

```
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/bin/odbc_update_ini.sh "/" "/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib" "oracle"
```

Arg1 - `/` = default directory for ODBC Driver Manager (root)

Arg2 - `/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib` = default library directory

Arg3 - `oracle` = any name you wish for the Driver name (used in DSN config)

---

With that, the script configured `/etc/odbcinst.ini` with the correct driver, and `/etc/odbc.ini` with most configurations.

I believe this way is correct because the script adds a bunch of configurations that are not obvious at first.

```
$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[oracle]
AggregateSQLType = FLOAT
Application Attributes = T
Attributes = W
BatchAutocommitMode = IfAllSuccessful
BindAsFLOAT = F
CacheBufferSize = 20
CloseCursor = F
DisableDPM = F
DisableMTS = T
DisableRULEHint = T
Driver = oracle
DSN = oracle
EXECSchemaOpt =
EXECSyntax = T
Failover = T
FailoverDelay = 10
FailoverRetryCount = 10
FetchBufferSize = 64000
ForceWCHAR = F
LobPrefetchSize = 8192
Lobs = T
Longs = T
MaxLargeData = 0
MaxTokenSize = 8192
MetadataIdDefault = F
QueryTimeout = T
ResultSets = T
ServerName = //[your_oracle_server]/[db_service]
SQLGetData extensions = F
SQLTranslateErrors = F
StatementCache = F
Translation DLL =
Translation Option = 0
UseOCIDescribeAny = F
```

And now I can access Oracle's DB.

```
$ isql oracle [USERNAME] [PASS]
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```